# Will jQuery-2.1.1.min.js or latest version jQuery-2.13.min.js doesn't support '@' character? If yes, then how to make it support '@'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

While checking a word "`#participant_test1@localhost`", in my code it enters `jquery-2.1.1.min.js` file's jquery.fn.init function where it checks the passed word with the pattern,
 `/^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/`.
So the check is failing. It is not supporting the presence of '@' character. Please give a solution.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery, (just javascript?).

Comment: Can you add your code please ?

Comment: You want to select an element which has an `id`like `#participant_test1@localhost`?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to "enter" jQuery.

Comment: Still don't get why someone would ever use `@` in an element ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can select an element like

```
<input type="text" id="participant_test1@localhost" value="Some Text"/>
```

With this selector

```
$("#participant_test1\\@localhost")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x1wc6xcb/